# Dataframe columns have numbers many of them in str format and many in float, how do I convert all of them to float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got a dataframe with columns with numerical values although just realised that many of them are 'str' (with commas in them) and many are floats. this is because its concatenation of multiple files and the datatype was inconsistent. what is the best way to convert all of them to floats?
I tried a few things

`PKupdated['DC'].astype(float)`
which gave me this error
`ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-1,519.97'`

tried replacing commas 
`PKupdated['DC'].str.replace(',','')`
but looks like that is converting all my floats to 'NaN'

is there any way I can convert str to float, in a way that existing floats are not affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use apply to differentiate between strings and floats:

```
PKupdated['DC'].apply(lambda x: float(x.replace(',', '')) if isinstance(x, str) else x)
```

Comment: thanks @mcsoini btw just realised its got "£" as well (apart from commas) how would you add that to your line?

Comment: `x.replace(',', '').replace('£', '')`